There is an error when I run and build my unity game on my android phone
I cannot solve this error for long hours.
I would like someone to help me...
I am using firebase in the unity game. I am not sure it influeces or not.
Thank you.
Unity:2022.3.25f1
Android:Rakuten Hand P710
AndroidOS:Android10
PC:Window10 Home
1st Error==============
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 8 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 30 in C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.25f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 30 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 30 (revision: 3)".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
=========================================================
2nd Error===============
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Failed to install the following SDK components:
platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30
The SDK directory is not writable (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.25f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK)


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 10s
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
=========================================================
3rd Error is too long but it looks like same error as 2nd one.
I don't write all 3rd error.
3rd Error================================
/////////////

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Failed to install the following SDK components:
platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30
The SDK directory is not writable (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.25f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK)


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
////////////


=========================================================
Please overcome the errors...
I just want to run my game on my android.

Did you try Run with --stacktrace? What were those results?  Your gradle file might help.
